# Use of 'messageListVisibility' in Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I was trying to filter mails based on the 'messageListVisibility' field of the labels assigned to the email. To be precise, I scan the labels of each email and if any of the labels has the messageListVisibility set to "hide", I don't show the email. This didn't work, so when I had a look at the labels returned by a call to "Users.labels: list", which retrieves all labels, I observed several things:

- The INBOX label has messageListVisibility = "hide"???
- The label "IMPORTANT" has messageListVisibility = "hide"???
- Several system labels do not have a messageListVisibility field.

The last point is manageable, but the two others are a bit surprising. Am I correct in assuming that the messageListVisibility field's objective is to not show the user any email that has that label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the purpose of the `messageListVisibility` attribute. The attribute determines if the **label name** is included alongside any messages which have this label. Consider the following:

- User has 5 messages in his INBOX. Each of which has labelA and labelB  applied to them.
- The `messageListVisibility` is `hide` for labelA and `show` for labelB.

When the user click on the Inbox and sees those 5 messages, labelB will show for each message in the list of messages, it's just to the left of the message subject.

The [documentation describes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels) `messageListVisibility` as:

*The visibility of messages with this label in the message list in the Gmail web interface. *

Comment: OK I misunderstood indeed. I was led astray by the part "visibility of messages" which made me think it influenced the displaying of messages and not of the labels. It's clear now and consistent with the behaviour I saw in the UI. Thanks.

Comment: @gwyers Consider upvoting and accepting his answer so others with the same question can find it :)